# What does "corrupt" etymologically mean?

Tags: etymology

I see that *interrupt* morphologically and semantically means 'to break something intermittently'.

I see that *corrupt* is formed from prefix 'co-' (which I know means "(put) together") and 'rupt' which stands for 'disruption' or 'break'. How do you break the stuff by putting its parts together? This sounds like oxymoron.

How can I understand the etymological roots of the word *corrupt*?

Comment: ***Corrupt***: mid-14c.  from com-, intensive prefix (see com-), + rup-, past participle stem of rumpere "to break".  http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=corrupt

Comment: Little Alien, I altered the formatting of your question and took about the bits about Russian. You can rollback the edits if you don't like them. You can also edit the question further if you choose to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word comes down to us straight from the Latin, [*corrumpo, corrumpere, corrupi, corruptus*](http://latin-dictionary.net/search/latin/corrump),

> 1. bribe, suborn
> 2. falsify
> 3. pervert, corrupt, deprave
> 4. seduce, tempt, beguile

This was in use even in ancient times.

According to the Oxford Latin Dictionary (sorry, no online link - it's a hard copy), *con-*, the prefix, was used to **intensify**:

> Expressing intensity of action

as well as to express simultaneity, joint action, connection, enclosure (e.g. *contain*), completeness (*complete* is an English word with this very meaning), etc.

So there are a number of words descended from Latin that begin with *co(n/m/r/etc.)* that do not imply *together*, *together with*, or *put together*.

As you stated "-rupt" (from *rumpo, rumpere, rupi, ruptum*) means break, but it also meant violate, infringe, overcome, and a number of other things. So one can't always deduce the exact meaning of a word by our often limited understanding of prefixes and root words today.

Answer (score 1):

*Corruptus* is the past participle of the Latin verb ***corrumpere*** - *to destroy, ruin, waste*. - *OED* & *Elementary Latin Dictionary*,Lewis (1947)

It appears in English- presumably from Norman French as *corrump*. :

> Etymology:  < Old French corompre, corrumpre (modern French corrompre
>   = Provençal corrompre, Italian corrompere) < Latin corrumpĕre to break in pieces, destroy, ruin, spoil, mar, adulterate, falsify, draw to
>   evil, seduce, bribe, < cor- together, altogether + rumpĕre to break,
>   violate, destroy, etc. In French also to spoil by decomposition, rot,
>   render putrid. (OED)

In the time of Chaucer the verb ***corrump*** was used to mean:

> 1. trans. To bring to naught, destroy, mar, spoil, render useless.
> 2. To decompose, cause to rot or decay; to infect or taint with corruption.

and especially, in view of the modern meaning:

> 3. To destroy morally, make morally corrupt. and
> 4. **To corrupt by bribery.**

By the late-fifteenth century the modern spelling seems to have appeared:

> 1474   Caxton tr. Game & Playe of Chesse (1883) ii. iii. 37   Be gold
>   ne siluer he shal not be corrupt ne corompid.

The above meanings and example are from the OED which records no instances of *corrump* since 1533.